# Stop timer on specific Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer

So I have this function that has a timer of 5 seconds and keeps repeating.

This timer executes a php script that checks for payments and if payment succeeded , it echos back to the main page as ajax response a 'transaction successful'.

The thing is that I want to stop that timer from executing when the 'msg' returns 'transaction successful' .

How can I achieve this? This is how my timer looks:

```
  var count = 5;
          setInterval(function () {
              count--;

              document.getElementById("fag").innerHTML = count;

              if (count === 0 ) {
                  count = 5;

                  $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: 'ajaxx.php',
                      data: {
                          'checkbalance': 'yes',
                          'email': '<?php echo $user->get_user_data()['email']; ?>',
                          'ip_taken': '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>'

                      },
                      success: function (msg) {

                          document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = msg;
                      }
                  });


              }

          }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store the interval id and use `clearInterval()` when message has response you want

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  count--;

  $("#fag").text(count);

  if (count === 0) {
    count = 5;
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajaxx.php',
    data: {
      'checkbalance': 'yes',
      'email': '<?php echo $user->get_user_data()['
      email ']; ?>',
      'ip_taken': '<?php echo $_SERVER['
      REMOTE_ADDR ']; ?>'

    },
    success: function(msg) {
      // clear interval when successful
      if (msg.trim() === 'transaction successful') {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
      $("#response").html(msg);
    }
  });

}, 1000);
```